# Can't add Liferay portlet from SVN to the App Server

Tags: eclipse, liferay

I'm checking out a Liferay portlet from SVN created by another developer into my Liferay 6.2 plugins SDK. This portlet is located at C:\Users\me\Liferay\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets

I then import the project at the root from the Liferay Plugins SDK into my Eclipse workspace

When I try to Right+click -> Add the project to the Liferay server it doesn't register. There are various applications created by others I've imported into the workspace but none of them deploy correctly unless I run a Liferay->SDK->deploy. The only thing that I can add directly to the server is the theme I've developed.

Specs:

- Eclipse Luna
- Liferay 6.2 EE bundled with Tomcat 7
- Liferay plugins SDK 6.2
- jdk-1.7

We've all been using Liferay 6.2 to develop our applications; Why are some reasons an imported portlet would fail to get added to the server?

Comment: Can you successfully `war` the module (right-click : Liferay -> SDK - > war) and deploy it using the App Manager within the portal? Are the modules utilizing Service Builder and perhaps require you to run that target? Do any of the modules have deployment dependencies on one another?

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: @Origineil I can deploy the war fine, but that doesn't allow me to debug the code (if I'm not mistaken. I'm not getting errors, just a bunch of logs returned from the app as normal, but the application never actually deploys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugins sdk assumes a certain directory structure and I'm not sure if you match that. Also, there's a configuration file named `build.username.properties` (replace *username* with your actual login name) at the root of the plugins sdk, pointing to the root directory of your liferay installation. This will need to be correctly configured for the build process to correctly associate the correct Liferay installation

Make sure that the plugin-sdk's version matches the Liferay version and the other developers didn't mess with the build processes (e.g. hardcoding their own additions and directory names)

Lastly, note that the plugins typically must be deployed through Liferay's deploy folder, not directly to the appserver. If only the deployment to Liferay fails, you can find the built plugins in your SDK's `dist` folder once Ant has done its job.

If your problems still persist, you might want to give more detail: mentioning "restart with a bunch of errors" is kind of hard to give the correct answer to.

Comment: Thank you Olaf, I've revised my question as it was written very hastily. It was my understanding that a portlet could be added directly to the server. If I do a deploy, how could I debug the code? I try but it tells me "Source not found" since all of the java code is compiled already

Comment: I've just found that if you lookup the source of the deployed war from the project you can debug the code. And a uniform build.user.properties worked as well, thanks Olaf